# Use UserControl as DataTemplate (with several bindings) in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a usercontrol that I use in several locations in my project. I use it to display a field, but the layout is different for different type of fields... It works fine when I use it in code and outside of any templates, but it doesn't when I use it in a datatemplate for my listview. The only thing it does is change the layout, but it doesn't show the values (like name & description).

I want to bind properties like Title, Description & Type which are attached properties, but they don't seem to work in the datatemplate... These are the properties:

```
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(ucBoardField), new UIPropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(UpdateTitle)));

    public string Description
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), typeof(ucBoardField), new UIPropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(UpdateDescription)));

    public string FieldTypeDescription
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FieldTypeDescriptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FieldTypeDescriptionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldTypeDescriptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FieldTypeDescription", typeof(string), typeof(ucBoardField), new UIPropertyMetadata("street", new PropertyChangedCallback(UpdateFieldTypeDescription)));
```

And these are their update methods:

```
    public static void UpdateTitle(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ucBoardField bf = sender as ucBoardField;
        if (bf == null) return;
        if (bf.Field == null) bf.Field = new Field();

        bf.Field.Title = (string)eventArgs.NewValue;
        bf.lblExtraTax.Text = bf.lblStation.Text = bf.lblStreetname.Text = bf.lblUtility.Text = bf.Field.Title;
    }
    public static void UpdateDescription(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ucBoardField bf = sender as ucBoardField;
        if (bf == null) return;
        if (bf.Field == null) bf.Field = new Field();

        bf.Field.Description = (string)eventArgs.NewValue;
        bf.lblCity.Text = bf.Field.Description;
    }
    public static void UpdateFieldTypeDescription(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ucBoardField bf = sender as ucBoardField;
        if (bf == null) return;
        if (bf.Field == null) bf.Field = new Field();
        if (bf.Field.FieldType == null) bf.Field.FieldType = new FieldType();

        bf.Field.FieldType.Description = bf.FieldTypeDescription = (string)eventArgs.NewValue;
        bf.ShowContent(); //updates layout
    }
```

They work fine when addressed in code, but all except for FieldTypeDescription show their results in the datatemplate, this is how I bind them:

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <uc:ucBoardField 
                    Id="{Binding Path=Field.Id}"
                    FieldTypeId="{Binding Path=Field.FieldTypeId}"
                    Title="{Binding Path=Field.Title}"
                    Description="{Binding Path=Field.Description}"
                    FieldTypeDescription="{Binding Path=FieldType.Description}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

In fact, they do work, but the data is not displayed...
Also, when their binding is triggered, I get an error (or warning) in my Output:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Field' property not found on 'object' ''Field' (HashCode=64502806)'. BindingExpression:Path=Field.Title; DataItem='Field' (HashCode=64502806); target element is 'ucBoardField' (Name=''); target property is 'Title' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Field' property not found on 'object' ''Field' (HashCode=64502806)'. BindingExpression:Path=Field.Description; DataItem='Field' (HashCode=64502806); target element is 'ucBoardField' (Name=''); target property is 'Description' (type 'String')
```

Property Field is just the object with all the information about the Field to display I get from the server.
And these are on my listview:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Title' property not found on 'object' ''TextBlock' (Name='lblTitle')'. BindingExpression:Path=Title; DataItem='TextBlock' (Name='lblTitle'); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='lblTitle'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Description' property not found on 'object' ''TextBlock' (Name='lblDescription')'. BindingExpression:Path=Description; DataItem='TextBlock' (Name='lblDescription'); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='lblDescription'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

It does not crash however...
Does anybody know what I might do wrong, why I get these errors and how I could solve them? I thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you setting up the ItemsSource for the listview and also the DataContext?

Comment: I'm getting a List of Fields and I add each Field through a foreach and lvw.items.add(field); ... I do not set the datacontext though

Comment: Should I set the DataContext if I don't use ItemsSource?

Comment: Typically you would set the DataContext to the object that holds the collection you are displaying. Your items source then becomes the binding to that collection. Your template would then explain how each field maps into the objects in the collection. This is somewhat at odds with what you are doing though because you are creating listview items programmatically instead of just maintaining a collection of objects that you bind to. Have you tried changing your bindings to template bindings?

Comment: @MarkSmith I've changed to maintaining a list of all my objects in codebehind, this list is now the itemssource of my listview with the object and I've set the datacontext of the listview with the objects to that list with all my objects (I receive that list from the server...) but it still has the same effect. Should I try to set two way-binding? Or is the problem rather related to my properties?
Yes I have, When I try that with 
`Id="{TemplateBinding Property=Id}"`
I get this error:
`Cannot find the static member IdProperty on the type ContentPresenter`...

Comment: I would load up Snoop which is available at [link](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). First run your app, then run Snoop, and there's a target in snoop that you drag onto your application. There's a filter drop down for binding errors. There's also a tab for data context once you select your item in the hierarchy. Make sure that the data context is showing the items you need to bind. Then make sure your bindings make sense given the tree. For any more troubleshooting, I'd want to have a running copy of the code you're working on. I feel like you need to set the dataContext differently.

Comment: @MarkSmith Snoop doesn't work on my application strangly enough (already tried it, it just snoops his own UI but displays is as if it's my apps UI. I can see my app's resources, but the content is Snoop's...) It's a very usefull tool though! :-)
This is how I set dataContext (when I receive all the fields):
`_previouslyUsedFields = allFields; lvwPreviousFields.ItemsSource = _previouslyUsedFields; lvwPreviousFields.DataContext = _previouslyUsedFields;`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem a few minutes ago:

You need to set the `DataContext`, but you CAN'T set it again in the control:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <uc:ucBoardField 
                DataContext="{Binding .}"
                Id="{Binding Path=Field.Id}"
                FieldTypeId="{Binding Path=Field.FieldTypeId}"
                Title="{Binding Path=Field.Title}"
                Description="{Binding Path=Field.Description}"
                FieldTypeDescription="{Binding Path=FieldType.Description}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But if you have the following (or similar) in your `UserControl` it won't work again, because the `DataContext` will be overwritten again:

```
<UserControl ...
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             ...>
```

Comment: I haven't set the DataContext in my uc, I'll try your first code example! :-)

Comment: Doesn't work with {Binding .}, is there anything else I should check? or do with the DataContext in codebehind?